# ButtonMode on Spark Image not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex-spark

i turned on buttonmode on a spark image and there is absolutely nothing happening there when i mouseover.

```
 <s:Image source="..." buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" />
```

i know that an image isn't a button by definition and there are button classes for this, but can anyone maybe clarify if this is expected behaviour or is there something general i am missing here?

thanks!

Comment: Is there a parent container that has `mouseChildren="false"`? Perhaps you should show more of the display list, because what you show ought to work.

Comment: the hierarchy here is application > bordercontainer > group > image. none of those has mousechildren set to false. i htought it might be some issue with the wmode, but that's also not true. it now shows that i only get this problem on macs. on windows ie9 it is working, so maybe it is a player issue.

Comment: btw, the mac's configuration: osx lion, firefox 5.0.1, flash player 10,3,181,26 (debug)

Comment: Sorry, don't have Mac at my disposal. Perhaps the Mac player handles transparent .png's differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small update: seems to me like a mac specific bug. since i upgraded my firefox to v6 everything is working smoothly again.